# How to enable auto-complete for every word I have typed in in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I am currently using Texstudio 2.12.22 on my macOS Catalina 10.15.3, I wonder how I can enable the auto-complete for every word I have typed in in the file?

*edit on 2020.3.23*
I've found two tools that satisfy my need:

- Latex extension in visual studio code
- overleaf.com

Comment: Do you mean what `ctrl + space` does?

Comment: @schtandard I am using macOS, and I've tried command + space which gives no response.

Comment: Maybe on of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764623/2919585) can help you? I don't have a Mac, so I can't test anything.

Comment: Wow @schtandard, when I came here I didn't expected such simple solution (+1 comment). Thanks. By the way: I'm on a Windows PC.

Comment: @schtandard It seems that it's not about the short-cut binding. I can not even use command + space or ctrl + space in Texstudio as short-cuts. But thank you very much for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: For people who search for similar question and finally come to this page, I recommend you to use latex extension in visual studio code or overleaf.com to write your latex document. The two tools I mention above support auto-complete for every word you have typed into the file even on macOS. If you are in similar situation like mine, you may try them.